# UICollectionView load Emoji with UILabel Memory grows and is not reclaimed

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit, uicollectionviewcell

I try to build a list like this

[image]

This is my Cell code

```
class EmojiCell: UICollectionViewCell {

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    makeUI()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    emojiLabel.text = nil
}

lazy var emojiLabel: UILabel = {
    let view = UILabel()
    view.font = UIFont(name: "Apple color emoji", size: 30)
    view.textAlignment = .center
    return view
}()

private func makeUI() {
    contentView.addSubview(emojiLabel)
    emojiLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    emojiLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    emojiLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    emojiLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    emojiLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
}

func setEmoji(emoji: String) {
    emojiLabel.text = emoji
}
}
```

As I scroll collectionview, the memory kept growing

[image]

Closing the page memory does not reclaim it

I found a memory leak in CFString

[image]

Can someone help me solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: It only happens with emojis?

Comment: @Moose Yes, I observed that the view cell is Reused